# References for the Keisler Order

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory, ultrapowers

Are there any good/modern references on the Keisler order. I have been reading Keisler's original paper, "Ultraproducts which are not Saturated", which introduces the order. However it is somewhat archaic and outdated (e.g. instead of writing $\prod_D \mathfrak{A}$, we writes $prod$-$D$ $\mathfrak{A}$). The paper also has some subtle errors and oddly cumbersome notation.

Furthermore, there are also sporadic "open-questions" spread throughout the paper and I believe many have been resolved since 1967. I gather this from tangential knowledge of the recent work on the order by Malliaris and Shelah.

$\mathbf{Searched}$: The following resources do not touch upon the Keisler order:

1) Chang and Keisler's "Model Theory"

2) Marker's "Model Theory: An Introduction"

3) Hodges's "Model Theory"

4) Google searching any variant of "Keisler order Model Theory"

$\mathbf{Particulars}$: I am looking for a reference which does the following:

1) Proves the Keisler order is a partial order

2) Proves the existence of a maximal class

3) Proves the existence of a non-minimal class

4) Proves the order is linear for stable theories

First note that Keisler's original paper does not show that the order is linear, he lists this as an open question. I would be pretty surprised if there is not one collected work that does not do the four things listed above. However, I haven't been able to find one that does so.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(4) is still wildly open; for (2) and (3), see theorem H in chapter 1 of Shelah's classification theory. I'm not sure what you mean by (1); if you meant "well-ordered" instead of "well defined," then that's also wildly open. EDIT: it seems immediate that the Keisler order is a partial order; am I missing something?

In general, Malliaris' thesis contains I think the best exposition and surveyn of the Keisler order, and page 3 of the thesis states Shelah's theorem H mentioned above.

I believe it is also wildly open whether the Keisler order is infinite, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. I had remembered what I had read incorrectly.

Comment: Keisler's original paper is based on very much on models instead of theories. A lot of the results begin "Assume that $\mathfrak{A}$ is $\alpha^+$ saturated and $\mathfrak{B}$ is $\alpha^+$ universal". He does show, eventually, that the Keisler order is a partial order, but it is not immediately obvious why ultrapowers of two elementary equivalent models become saturated by exactly the same the same ultrafilters.

Comment: Furthermore, (4) is no longer open (as I have changed it). This is a result in Shelah's Classification theory (or which Malliaris attributes to Shelah's Classification theory). The point of this post is to find a single source which has all of these results together.

Comment: So the definition of Keisler order I'm familiar with is that $T_1\le T_2$ if whenever $U$ is a regular ultrafilter on $\lambda$, $M_i\models T_i$, and $Ult(M_2, U)$ is $\lambda^+$-saturated, then $Ult(M_1, U)$ is $\lambda^+$-saturated. Using this definition, poset-ness is immediate. I'm surprised to hear that (4) is no longer open; where in Shelah's book is that, or do you have another citation? Last I asked Maryanthe, she said (if I recall correctly) that it was still open.

Comment: Right, that is the correct definition of the Keisler order. However, one needs to show that this actually works, i.e. one needs to show that the ultrapowers are not model dependent, but theory dependent (since ultraproducts, are by defintion, constructions on models). This is done in Keisler's paper.

Comment: I believe (4) is answered on page 2 of math.uchicago.edu/~mem/mm-quantifiers-final.pdf, with reference to Shelah's paper. I might be mistake, but I believe that this demonstrates a linear order. The actual reference is [12] S. Shelah, Classification Theory and the number of non-isomorphic models, rev. ed. North-Holland, 1990.

Comment: I think that just talks about stable theories.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I had edited my question to incorporate that detail.

Comment: Given the edit, I'm pretty sure Shelah's book might be the answer to your question. Unrelatedly, re: your comment on being a partial order, now I see: transitivity is obvious but reflexivity is not.

Comment: Personally, I was hoping that I wouldn't need to start reading that yet. I've heard it is notoriously difficult. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @KyleGannon I also believe that you can find answers to all four of your questions in Classification Theory, and I'm sure this is the best place to look. I don't know of anything written about Keisler's order that wasn't written by Keisler, Shelah, or Malliaris.

Comment: @NoahS It is now known that Keisler's order is *not* a well-order. There is an infinite strictly decreasing sequence within the simple theories.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that! Do you have a citation?

Comment: Just [this](https://www.msri.org/workshops/686/schedules/18403) talk Maryanthe gave at MSRI in May. But there's no video or slides available, and I didn't take notes. I believe this particular result has not been written up yet, but it's a continuation of the work in [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2919v1.pdf) paper, which is interesting it its own right: it shows that (assuming a compact cardinal!) simplicity is a dividing line for Keisler's order.

Comment: I can also tell you want the theories in this decreasing sequence are (if my memory serves correctly): For $k\geq 2$, let $L_k$ be the language consisting of a single $k$-ary relation symbol. Let $T_k$ be the theory of the Fraïssé limit of the class of $k$-ary hypergraphs omitting a complete hypergraph on $(k+1)$ vertices. So $T_2$ is the theory of the generic triangle-free graph, $T_3$ is the theory of the generic tetrahedron-free $3$-hypergraph, etc. Then $T_k$ is simple for $k\geq 3$ (not $k=2$!) and $T_{k+1}$ is strictly below $T_k$ in Keisler's order.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: That's awesome! Thank you

Comment: @KyleGannon A tiny comment: in _Classification Theory_, reflexivity is shown by appeal to 1.9 (p.330); I think 1.9 can be proved without reference to game-theoretic arguments, and follows from Keisler's results on saturation, of which there is a textbook presentation in section 13 of _The Theory of Ultrafilters_ by Comfort and Negrepontis; maybe it is slightly easier because ultrafilters are used, rather than the filters of 1.9, although people's tastes differ. Theorems 4.3 and 5.8 (chapter VI, section 4) of _Classification Theory_ look to me the right references you need for (2) and (3).

Answer (score 3):

In reply to the last comment by Noah, I may mention the following result by Malliaris-Shelah, from their paper ``[KEISLER’S ORDER HAS INFINITELY MANY CLASSES](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08341v2.pdf)
''

> We prove, in ZFC, that there is an infinite strictly descending
>   chain of classes of theories in Keisler’s order. Thus Keisler’s order is infinite
>   and not a well order. Moreover, this chain occurs within the simple unstable
>   theories, considered model-theoretically tame.